# Using no article with "tous" and "toutes"

Tags: grammaire, articles

In the song [Enfant de tous pays](http://www.paroles.net/enrico-macias/paroles-enfants-de-tous-pays) there is a line

> Enfants de tous pays
>
> Et de toutes couleurs

Normally I would expect "tous **les** pays" and "toutes **les** couleurs". Why is there no definite article here? Is it correct to say something like this?

> Tous étudiants de l'école doivent faire leurs devoirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just an "artistic" form.

Indeed, for your last sentence for instance, you should definetely say "Tous les étudiants de..."

[Here is](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/enfants-de-tous-pays-children-all-countries.html) a probably very approximate translation of the song lyrics, but that may help you make appropriate parallal with English song writters taking liberties with the language ;)